# Naive Bayes text classifier with features such as hasDate, hasLocation, first word etc

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, classification

I'm trying to work on a Naive Bayes text classifier. I have already created a bag of words approach in code. In my documents I have noticed many features that  are unique to certain classifications. Examples of these features include whether or not the document contains a location , date or name. These are all Boolean values and could be determined before the text is classified. There are other features such as what is the first word etc.

I understand the basic Naive Bayes approach. But have failed to find information on incorporating these features within a classifier.

My question is if it is possible to include the features I mentioned above with bag of words? If so is there an example of this, that I could follow. If this is not the case what would you recommend?

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the Naive Bayes framework, nothing prevents you from adding additional features that aren't based on a bag-of-words representation. Let's say you have a class likelihood p(document|class_1) = l_1 based on your bag of words features. You have reason to believe that some binary features b_1 and b_2 will also help in the classification (these can be document containing a date and time respectively, to make the example concrete).

You estimate the probability p(b_1 = 1 | class_1) = (# of docs in class 1 with b_1 = 1) / (#of docs in class 1)---p(b_1 = 0 | class_1) = 1 - p(b_1 = 1 | class_1). You do the same for class 2, and for the feature b_2 for both classes. Now to add these features to the classification rule is particularly simple, since Naive Bayes just assumes feature independence. So:

p( class_1 | document ) \propto p(class_1) x l_1 x p(b_1|class_1) x p(b_2|class_1)

where l_1 means the same as before (likelihood based on BOW features), and for the p(b_i|class_1) terms you use either the p(b_i=1|class_1) or p(b_i=0|class_1) terms depending on what the value of b_i actually was. This can be extended to non-binary features in the same way, and you can keep adding to your heart's content (although you should be aware that you're assuming *independence* between the features, and you may wish to switch to a classifier that doesn't make this assumption).

Comment: Thank you for your response, this is very helpful. I have one more question though. In the bag of words approach I use Laplace smoothing to eliminate the probability of the class being 0 due to the p(word|class) being 0. Would it be correct if I applied this same smoothing to my binary features. so p(b_1=1|class_1) =
(# of docs in class 1 with b_1 = 1) + 1 / (#of docs in class 1) + 2.

Comment: hello Ben, p( class_1 | document ) \propto p(class_1)  in this what is \propto please, can u explain this statement.

Comment: It's proportional to: the posterior of interest is proportional to the prior class probability * class likelihood (the normalisation constant is \sum_class p(class) p(features|class))